# mdadm not using all the disks

Tags: raid, mdadm

I can't find the exact answer for my question so I decided to post it here.
Few years ago I did a RAID0 `mdadm` for my home server, mostly for data hoarding. I used 4 drives of 3 tb each one, today I was checking around and I found that `mdadm` is not using the whole disks (I'm not totally sure though but seems to for the outputs).

Is that right?
If it is right, how can I make `mdadm` to use the whole disks?

Output of `lsblk` is:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk     
└─sda1   8:1    0     2T  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk     
└─sdb1   8:17   0     2T  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0     2T  0 part 
sdd      8:48   0   2.7T  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   0     2T  0 part 
sde      8:64   1   7.2G  0 disk 
└─sde1   8:65   1   1.9G  0 part 
sdf      8:80   0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sdf1   8:81   0 114.4G  0 part /
├─sdf2   8:82   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdf5   8:85   0   4.9G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Output of `df -h` is:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sdf1       113G  1.7G  106G   2% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  155M  1.5G  10% /run
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md0         11T  8.0T  2.4T  77% /mnt/raid0
```

Output of `parted` is:

[image: parted output]

Comment: @Zx485 Next time please remove the extra [enter]s before formatting as text.  (see my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1162743/revisions) ).  **Thank you!  ;-)**

Comment: Thanks for the formatting helpping! It was a mess :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok everyone! Actually nevermind.
That lsblk is showing tebibytes, if you do a lsblk -b its shown as bytes and the capacity is totally right.

Sorry for my noobness.